# Is it possible to do an operation only if DATETIME is smaller than NOW() at some time interval?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `REPLACE INTO` operation done in my database, but I would like to make it happen only if the time in that same table for that P_ID is less than 10 minutes let's say.

**`table_a`**

```
P_ID    CHECK   DATETIME
===================================
10      1       2013-06-27 13:23:23
5       0       2013-06-24 11:14:02
```

::

```
REPLACE INTO table_a (P_ID,CHECK,DATETIME) VALUES ('5','1','2013-06-24 11:10:00');
```

So, I would like this REPLACE to **NOT** happen because it hasn't been 10 minutes since last update.

Is this possible? Or does it take another query?

Comment: `REPLACE INTO` does [not have a WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003244/does-replace-into-have-a-where-clause)... Is that your question?

Comment: No, I would like the REPLACE to happen providing the time window is big enough, say ten minutes bigger than what it says for that row in the DB, in my example P_ID #5

Comment: Are you doing this in procedural logic or SQL. As REPLACE INTO does not have a WHERE clause I don't see how (not a MySQL expert) you could do this in SQL...

Comment: In English, what problem are you trying to solve? (Replace may not be the best or simplest option)

Comment: @Bohemian, a REPLACE INTO a table with a condition referring the DATETIME value

Comment: @Ted: Once again, in **plain English** (without using `REPLACE INTO` in your words), please describe what you're trying to accomplish here. `REPLACE INTO` may not be the way to do it, and you're fixated on using that phrase. Put it into a plain, textual description of what you want your end result to be, without using any SQL terms. A plain `UPDATE` with a `WHERE` clause, for instance, might be exactly what you need instead.

Comment: ok Ken, I thought I should be quick and to the point, but here goes: I need a feed table to update when something new happens. If that thing has happened within a ten minute interval, then it won't update. Also the feeds have F_ID which MUST Auto Increment for every update, this is why I used REPLACE_INTO, because it does the change for the autoinc field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE1:** You can wrap your `REPLACE INTO` into a stored procedure

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_replace(IN pid INT, IN chk INT, IN dt DATETIME)
BEGIN
  IF 10  < COALESCE(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, 
            (SELECT datetime FROM table_a WHERE p_id = pid), dt), 11) THEN
    REPLACE INTO table_a (p_id, `check`, datetime) VALUES (pid, chk, dt);
  END IF;    
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c20ec/1)** demo

Assuming that `P_ID` has unique constraint on it, you can use `INSERT ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to do it's job like this

```sql
INSERT INTO table_a (p_id, `check`, datetime)
SELECT 5, 1, '2013-06-24 11:10:00'
  FROM table_a
 WHERE 10 < COALESCE(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2013-06-24 11:00:00', 
           (SELECT datetime FROM table_a WHERE p_id = 5)), 11)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `check` = VALUES(`check`), datetime = VALUES(datetime);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e572d/1)** demo

**Note:** both `REPLACE INTO` and `INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY` change auto incremented primary key (f_id in your case)

Comment: Thanks peterm, I have just commented to Ken about my problem in my own question

Comment: @Ted i think you have to modify last line like this `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID=VALUES(F_ID), check = VALUES(check), datetime = VALUES(datetime)`, please see this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d299c/1

Comment: @Ted See updated answer. Bot solutions should work you. Auto increment PK is changed in both cases which is what you want if understand correctly.