# Update database query

Tags: php

What I want to achieve is to add 30 days to a customers subscription if the payment has been made

So I am using this code

```
$set = "REPLACE into CLIENTS where USR_PAID = '1' and USR_EXPIRATION = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 0 DAY)) values ('USR_EXPIRATION','" . $due . "')";
$update = $conn->update($set, $db);
```

I am getting the following syntax error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server        version for the right syntax to use near 'where USR_PAID = '1' and USR_EXPIRATION =   DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 0 DAY)) values ' at line 1
>       Statement:
>       REPLACE into CLIENTS where USR_PAID = '1' and USR_EXPIRATION = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 0 DAY)) values ('USR_EXPIRATION', '09-05-2013')

I should tell you that I am using the same function to update the db in different parts of the website and is working just fine.

Also the following query is working and gives me all the clients that have paid and expire today:

```
$request = "select * from CLIENTS where USR_PAID = '1' and USR_EXPIRATION = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))";
$result = $conn->query($request, G_NORMDB);
```

I guess it is only a syntax error that I can't figure out.

Comment: your adding a char in USR_PAID = '1' right now, shouldn't that be USR_PAID=1 or USR_PAID=true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a side note,I think this won't work anyway, you can't use `replace into` to selectively change columns.

Here's the manual's explanation:

> Values for all columns are taken from the values specified in the
>   REPLACE statement. Any missing columns are set to their default
>   values, just as happens for INSERT. You cannot refer to values from
>   the current row and use them in the new row.

So you muse include the whole user row.

I think it's easier to just use this query:

$q = "UPDATE `CLIENTS` SET `USR_EXPIRATION` = '$due' WHERE `USR_PAID = '1' AND USR_EXPIRATION = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))";
$update = $conn->update($q, $db);

let me know how that works for you, if it does at all.

Comment: Thank you very much Mostafa, now it works.. As you may understand i am very novice with PHP!! Thank you all for helping me.

Comment: No problems at all :) keep working and you'll be there, I've been working with php for many years and still consider myself a novice too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your REPLACE syntax is wrong. VALUES, then WHERE.

```
$set = "REPLACE into CLIENTS (the two columns here) VALUES ('USR_EXPIRATION','" . $due . "') where USR_PAID = '1' and USR_EXPIRATION = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))";
```

Read up more on [enter link description here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) for more information.

**Edit:** I was curious about not seeing WHERE in the documentation. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003244/does-replace-into-have-a-where-clause), REPLACE does not have a WHERE clause. Use UPDATE instead.

Answer (score -1):

What about following the very advice from the error message - to check Mysql manual on the syntax for the [REPLACE query?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)

Comment: I already did many times and as i told you i have used the replace into query several times in the website and is always working