# how I make a single query for both insert and update?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert-update

Suppose we have a mysql table something like this

`id, userid, days, start, and close`

and we have data for each columns like this -

```
1, 3, mon, 01.00, 02.00,
2, 3, tue, 03.00, 05.00,
3, 3, wed, 04.00, 06.00,
4, 3, thu, 05.00, 07.00,
5, 3, fri, 06.00, 08.00,
6, 3, sat, 07.00, 10.00,
7, 3, sun, 08.00, 12.00,
```

with this data, I need to update or insert my table. (if userid is not exist in table it should be insert or if userid exist in db it should be update.)

Can I know, is there a way to make a mysql single query for this? I tried it with `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` there I can only edit single row that mean I can not insert or update table with multiple rows using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

At the moment I have used 2 different queries for inset and update

This is my insert query -

```
$q = "INSERT INTO availability (userid, days, opentime, closetime) 
        VALUES (?, 'Monday', ?, ?),
                 (?, 'Tuesday', ?, ?),
                 (?, 'Wednesday', ?, ?),
                 (?, 'Thursday', ?, ?),
                 (?, 'Friday', ?, ?),       
                 (?, 'Saturday', ?, ?),                         
                 (?, 'Sunday', ?, ?)";                          
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'issississississississ', 
                                            $userId, $monOpen, $monClose, 
                                            $userId, $tueOpen, $tueClose,
                                            $userId, $wedOpen, $wedClose,
                                            $userId, $thuOpen, $thuClose,
                                            $userId, $friOpen, $friClose,
                                            $userId, $satOpen, $satClose,
                                            $userId, $sunOpen, $sunClose);                          
            // Execute the query:
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: Just add a unique index on `(userid, days)` and you can use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax.

Comment: @ypercube I think I can not use unique index in this table reason is I want to add 7 rows for one particular user. clear?

Comment: @ypercube, tell me can I make `userid and days` to unique index with my requirements?

Comment: I myself use a trigger on insert for this and just run INSERT statements against the table. But I was not familiar with the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a unique index on `(userid, days)`:

```sql
-- run this only once
ALTER TABLE  availability 
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX userid_days_UQ         -- just a name for the index
    (userid, days) ;
```

then you can use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax:

```php
$q = "
```

```sql
      INSERT INTO availability 
          (userid, days, opentime, closetime) 
      VALUES 
          (?, 'Monday', ?, ?),
          (?, 'Tuesday', ?, ?),
          (?, 'Wednesday', ?, ?),
          (?, 'Thursday', ?, ?),
          (?, 'Friday', ?, ?),       
          (?, 'Saturday', ?, ?),                         
          (?, 'Sunday', ?, ?)
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
          opentime = VALUES(opentime),
          closetime = VALUES(closetime) ;
```

```php
     ";
```

Comment: If you have duplicate data (e.g just 2 rows with same `userid` and `days`) then the `ALTER TABLE` will fail.

Comment: I just checked with your code. Its only insert one row to my db. Here its data for Monday. Updating also not working.

Comment: Why do you have 2 unique constraints, separately on `userid` and `days`. Don't you want to store data for many users (and 7 rows per user)? This way you have defined the table, you can't insert more than one row per user.

Comment: Yes I want 7 rows per user.. sorry for misunderstand.. wait I will check it again

Comment: Then remove the `UNIQUE(userid)` and `UNIQUE(days)` and add only one: `UNIQUE(userid,days)` in the CREATE TABLE (or use the ALTER TABLE statement above)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36908/discussion-between-tnk-and-ypercube)

Answer (score 1):

Having separate queries is a very common practice, there is nothing wrong with it. However, at least mySQL offers a `replace into` command:

```
REPLACE INTO availability
    (userid, days, opentime, closetime) VALUES
    (?,    'Monday', ?,         ?);
```

The only drawback is, that you can not specify a where clause.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3046980/1596455 as well.