# Stop MySQL incrementing ID on duplicate key name (not inserting)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

```
START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO `a` (`name`, `age`) 
    VALUES (:age, :danger)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name), age = VALUES(age);

    INSERT INTO `b` (`age`, `danger`) 
    VALUES (:age, :danger)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE age = VALUES(age), danger = VALUES(danger);            
COMMIT;
```

The above SQL transaction is increasing the auto increment value even if there is a duplicate entry. Is there any way to stop it from incrementing the value if it's simply updating the values (not inserting them)?

Comment: [From the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html): *If the statement updates a row instead, LAST_INSERT_ID() is not meaningful.*

Comment: is the id Auto increment in the table schema?

Comment: @Jaan Yes that is correct. If it is a duplicate key it will update the relevant fields but also increment the ID value (which I do not want it to do).

Comment: Try [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) and make the field unique

Comment: @Damodaran Could you post an answer with an example replace statement?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003244/does-replace-into-have-a-where-clause for replace

Comment: It is very easy, just change the INSERT keyword to REPLACE and rest of the query is same. REPLACE INTO `b` (`age`, `danger`) 
    VALUES (:age, :danger)