# $this->db->replace() using where

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, query-builder

I'm trying to find something along the lines of `insert_or_update` (similar to what Laravel offers) in CodeIgniter 3. The closest I have found is `$this->db->replace()`, but I can't find anything that specifies that it can/can't be used alongside a `->where()`. Based on the docs I don't believe this will work since it doesn't list `->where()` as an option, but I wanted to double check this as well.

I'm hoping I can do something like...

```
$data = [...];
$whereSearch = [...];
$this->db->replace($data)->where($whereSearch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here to quote the documentation is

> using PRIMARY and UNIQUE keys as the determining factor.

Replace only works based on your keys to replace the values in a table. You might find [Does replace into have a where clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003244) helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where('column_name',$compared_data); 
$this->db->set('column_name',$updated_data);
$this->db->update('table_name');
```

Would this be what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't believe so. I was wanting a single function call that would determine if an `insert` or an `update` should be performed. The `replace()` function seemed like an option that might work, but the data that I'm needing this for doesn't have the required keys in this instance.