# Cant seem to use REPLACE INTO with WHERE EXISTS

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to ensure Replace is only done if the a competition with the specified name doesnt exist, or if it does exist, it has a specified userID.

```
REPLACE INTO ClimbingDB.competitions(competitionName) 
VALUES ('Competition Name') 
WHERE (NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM ClimbingDB.competitions 
    WHERE competitionName='Competition Name') 
OR EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM ClimbingDB.competitions 
    WHERE competitionName='Competition Name' AND userID='5'))
```

I get a "You have an error in your SQL syntax".

This SQL statement worked if I do a ""SELECT * FROM ClimbingDB.competitions" instead of the REPLACE and The REPLACE statement also works fine without there WHERE condition.

Comment: See [REPLACE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) You can't use `WHERE` with `REPLACE`. It just replaces the row whose primary key matches the replacement values. Use `UPDATE` to update rows conditionally.

Comment: Replace has no Where Clause try some thing like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003244/does-replace-into-have-a-where-clause

Comment: If the competition name doesn't exist, you want to change all the other rows to this competition name? If not, which row do you want to replace? If you want to add a new row, that's done with `INSERT`, not `REPLACE` or `UPDATE`.

Comment: You can't do them both in one query, unless you can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`, but it doesn't look like that works here.